# Efficient way to remove overlapping sections of polygons in Python

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I have "tiers" of polygons that might overlap. Each tier could contain any number of polygons. If a polygon from tier 1 overlaps with one from tier 2, I would like to remove the overlapping portion of the tier 2 polygon (not the entire polygon, just the overlap). I am looking for a very efficient way to do this.

Here's an example setup:

```
tier_1_polys = [[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]], [[2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3], [3, 2], [2, 2]]]
tier_2_polys = [[[0, 0], [0, 2], [2, 2], [2, 0], [0, 0]]]
tier_3_polys = [[[0, 0], [0, 2], [2, 2], [2, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 3], [3, 3], [3, 0], [0, 0]]]
tiered_polys = {1: tier_1_polys, 2: tier_2_polys, 3: tier_3_polys}
```

Here's the "brute force" solution where I just for-loop through everything. It works but I would like to know if there's a more efficient solution. As you can tell it's going to be even slower for additional tiers because I want to remove polygons in all the lower tiers.

```
def remove_polys(polys: List[List], lower_tier_polys: List[List]) -> List[List]:
    cleaned_polys = []
    for poly in polys:
        poly = Polygon(poly)
        for lower_tier_poly in lower_tier_polys:
            lower_tier_poly = Polygon(lower_tier_poly)
            poly = poly - lower_tier_poly
    # handle edge case where Polygon is split into MultiPolygon
    if isinstance(poly, MultiPolygon):
        cleaned_polys.append([list(p.exterior.coords) for p in list(poly)])
    else:
        cleaned_polys.append(list(poly.exterior.coords))
    return cleaned_polys


def remove_overlapping_polys(polys: dict):

    cleaned_poly1s = polys[1]
    cleaned_poly2s = remove_polys(polys[2], polys[1])
    cleaned_poly3s = remove_polys(polys[3], polys[1] + polys[2])

    return cleaned_poly1s, cleaned_poly2s, cleaned_poly3s
```